# How to append a comma to the end of strings when saving to a bundle?

Tags: android

I have an activity that allows the user to pick a contact and it returns with the contact number and enter's it in a EditText.

Now the problem is, if the user enter's a number before they pick a contact the number will be gone when the activity is resumed.

I know i can user a bundle to save the state of the UI. The only problem is after the user enter's the number in the EditText i would like to add a comma to the end of the number automatically when the results are passed back in from the contact picker.

This is what i have so far..

```
EditText numbers = null;
numbers = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNumbers);

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onResume();
    //opening my database
    mDbHelper.open();
    setRowIdFromIntent();
    //populating some fields 
    populateField();
```

Here is my onSavedInstanceState()...

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if(mRowId != null){
    //Here just keeping a reference of a db ID i use
    outState.putLong(DbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
}
```

How would i save the edit text to the bundle and append a comma at the end?
Also is it possible to know when a user enters 10 digits and automatically append a (,) comma at the end?

EDIT:

Here is what i managed to come up with but it isnt working.

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("number", numbers.getText().toString().trim());
```

}

Then in onRestore()

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState){
super.onResume();
mDbHelper.open();
if(currentNumber != null){
currentNumber = outState.getString("number").toString() + ",;
}
```

with this code it is just replacing the current number when the activity it resumed

Comment: you need to paste more code from populateFields and setRowIdFromIntent. also please format your code a little

Answer (score 1):

Since you are storing the DB id field of the element instead of the number, you cannot append a comma at the end. You COULD however simply append a comma at the end upon resume.

While I don't know what your populateField() method looks like, I'm guessing at some point you set the EditText to the value of some db entry. Just add a comma at the end.

```
myEditText.setText(someVariable + ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

From the first look it looks pretty simple. I am assuming you are setting the text using `setText(CharSequence text);` in your `onResume()` method. Simply just add the `";"` character after your saved number :

```
   editText.setText(myString+";");
```

To know when the user has allready added 10 digits you could set a `TextWatcher` using [`addTextChangedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29). And inside the [`afterTextChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29) method you check if the input length is greater than 10 chars and just append a comma to your `EdiText`.

Comment: So basically what it is is, the user has the ability to enter a number in the edit text(telephone number) then they can pick a contact to add to it. So when they click the pick contact buttona and pick a contact. the number is returned. What i am trying to do is keep the number(s) that the user entered before they went to pick a contact and add them to the edit text when the user returns. lets say if the user enter's a number and picks a contact, and the picks another. i want all of these numbers to still be availible when the user returns.

Comment: and set to the edit text. I know i may be making this more complicated than it is.